# How to know I am interacting with a fragment?

Tags: applications

How do I identify that I'm interacting with a [fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)? My understanding about fragments is not quite clear and I presume that they are about UI, always requires an Activity to be shown with it and are supposed to be modular in nature. They do not come with their own View unlike a full blown Activity.

Anyhow, here's the problem: the app [My Android Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.myandroidtools) offers UI that *appears to be* multi-pane and multi-window. For example: if I launch the app and choose *Database*, the activity remains the same i.e. *cn.wq.myandroidtools/.MainActivity* but the view on the UI changes. If I choose *SharedPreferences* the Activity still remains the same yet the view on the UI changes.

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Here's what I've tried:

- I've closely monitored logcat and it didn't reveal anything useful.
- I've tried `dumpsys activity window windows` and other than the same activity I didn't find anything of use to me.
- I've tried `dumpsys activity activities` and `dumpsys activity -p cn.wq.myandroidtools`. Former didn't yield anything significant and the latter provided output which multiple mentions of the term *fragments*, yet I couldn't understand what I was dealing with.
- I've already checked the manifest and there is no Activity that points to the entry *Database* would cause to open.

Assuming a fragment may be misinterpretation but then how would I verify I'm wrong?

There's more: this is not an XY problem. Yes, I can look for an app that offers the same feature which the said app provides under *Database* entry. I already found two alternatives and I don't want to use them.

Why? *Because I want to learn* since fragments are not limited to the said app but are used heavily by Settings app and many other apps out in the wild. If only I get to understand what particular fragment I'm dealing with, I may be able to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21844594/4988230) to always have the said app show the UI meant for *Database* entry, whenever launched from app drawer.

## In short

- I'm looking for a way to realize that I'm interacting with a fragment;
- What about that fragment do I need to use in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21844594/4988230) to show it?

If it is of importance: I'm using Nexus 6 with stock and rooted Android 6.0.1. It would be fine if you provide answers tested on stock Android 5.0.x or 5.1.x.

Comment: `dumpsys activity top`,this command will show the detail of the current activity,containing the current fragment.